# Download the latest file from URL

Tags: powershell

Really having a tough time with this one.  We download a weekly file from a URL.  I need to only download the newest file each week.  I can't figure out how to grab the latest file.  The file will always be WAYYYYMMDD.zip

```
$Url = "http://files.test.com/zips/weekly/WAYYYYMMDD.zip"
$Path = "C:\temp\WA2343.zip"
$Username = "*******"
$Password = "********"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

Comment: would it be a solution to count dates backwards and stop on the first file found?

Comment: The file is released on the exact same day every week, so it could look for GetDate() or something.  Just not sure how to integrate that into the scrdipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Url = "http://files.test.com/zips/weekly/WA$CurrentDate.zip"
$Path = "C:\temp\WA$CurrentDate.zip"
$Username = "*******"
$Password = "********"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

Save the script and run it as a Windows scheduled task on the day of the week when the file is released.

Answer (score 0):

the proposed solution should work but here is another version with some error handling:

```
$filename = 'WA{0}.zip' -f  (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd')
$uri = "http://files.test.com/zips/weekly/$filename"

try
{
    #This is to check if the URl exists or not
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Head -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop

    #if the above call succeeded without errors then download file
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile (Join-Path C:\temp -ChildPath    $filename) -Credential (Get-Credential) -TimeoutSec 60
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning ('Cant find the URL: {0}' -f $uri)
}
```